# Materialize CSS autocomplete with JQuery UI error Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, materialize

I'm using Materialize CSS library and in that, there is an option to make [autocomplete dropdown](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) (you can find that at the end of the page)

if I try to use that, when I typing something it is showing me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._search (http://localhost/imgup/js/jquery-ui.min.js:2345:101)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._search (http://localhost/imgup/js/jquery-ui.min.js:139:77)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).search (http://localhost/imgup/js/jquery-ui.min.js:2341:175)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).search (http://localhost/imgup/js/jquery-ui.min.js:139:77)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function). (http://localhost/imgup/js/jquery-ui.min.js:2337:74)
>       at i (http://localhost/imgup/js/jquery-ui.min.js:302:62)

I searched for this question but I didn't find any useful answers

this is my Materialize CSS - HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
```

and this is javascript for autocomplete

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
data: {
"Apple": null,
"Microsoft": null,
"Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
},
limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
onAutocomplete: function(val) {
// Callback function when value is autcompleted.
},
minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
});
```

and there are some screenshots that where I'm getting error as below error log

Error in console:
[image: Error in console]

Error in file that is occurring - 1:
[image: Error in file that is occurring - 1]

Error in file that is occurring - 2:
[image: Error in file that is occurring - 2]

Error in file that is occurring - 3:
[image: Error in file that is occurring - 3]

Error in file that is occurring - 4:
[image: Error in file that is occurring - 4]

Error in file that is occurring - 5:
[image: Error in file that is occurring - 5]

how can I fix this? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of jQuery/Materialize are you using? Check out this pen where it's working:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpBRjJ

Did you wrap your jQuery code in something like `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: jQuery v2.2.4 and materialize css 0.98, in materialize css official page it is working, but in local it is not

Comment: this.surce is returning null value

Comment: What are you using to include the files? Just individual script tags? A build tool? Try including jQuery and Materialize via the CDN and then report back

Comment: yeah, it worked, I didn't notice that I'm using old CDN of materialize files, after changing that I rearranged material links and jquery UI links, thank you. happy for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading `jquery-ui` then the error

> this.source is not a function"

also occurs.

In that case you can't use the jquery `$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete()` but will need to use the `M.Autocomplete` alternative calls.